# If ARC is handled by the compiler, why is weak not supported on iOS 4 and Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Supposedly `weak` is like `assign` or `unsafe_unretained`, except that a `weak` variable is "zeroed" when the object that it points to is `dealloc`'ed.  But ARC is handled by the compiler, so why is `weak` not supported on iOS 4 and Mac OS X 10.6?

(for this question please don't give a guess as an answer, but something more supported by facts/reference/docs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `__weak` requires zeroing out one or more pointers in places other than the current object, additional data structures are required to keep track of weak references. This is in contrast to `__strong`, `__unsafe_unretained`, and `__autoreleasing`, which do not require additional tracking. The tracking structures and programs for manipulating them are built into the OS; the compiler inserts the code to perform the calls, but the OS support needs to be there in order for the compiled code to work.

Answer (score 2):

`__weak` references require runtime support which isn't available on the older iOS versions.

Comment: and I guess the question is... why?  Can't the compiler handle it?  By the way, is it true that if there are 12 objects having 12 weak references to that one object, once that object is `dealloc`'ed, all 12 weak references are zeroed?

Comment: The compiler can't do it because it doesn't know where all the weak references are for an object at a given time. The runtime needs to keep track of this with a special API which the compiler generates calls to.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical reason why 10.6 could not support weak references, and indeed there is at least one third-party implementation available (e.g. [this one](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/introducing-plweakcompatibility.html)). Apple decided to support ARC but without weak references. I doubt anybody who knows the actual reason Apple made that choice is allowed to post it on stackoverflow... so all you can do is speculate.